# Updating Qt documentation links throughout the site

Tags: discussion, editing-help, external-links, broken-link

I love [Qt](http://www.qt.io/). Other than the awesome documentation they have, the community support for it here on SO has been very nice. But with [Digia](http://www.digia.com/) buying them, they seem to be changing the URLs for the documentation now, as they have moved to what seems to be a completely new site.

e.g. http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qgraphicsview.html

has changed to: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html

Considering that it's (I hope) only the initial part of the URLs that has changed (can't find an official statement by them on their website regarding it), is there a way to update such links, automatically throughout the site? Can we contact them to confirm if it's only the initial part that will be changed?

There are just too many of these links lying around and editing them manually is just too much a task.

Comment: Hmm, the transformation between the first url and the second is not clear to me.

Comment: [1847 hits](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Adoc.trolltech.com)

Comment: Hmpf. A shame they didn't keep the old versions up, even if at the new URL. Because it's conceivable that people refer to a specific version on-purpose, and it's actually important (So try pointing the old versions to archive.org for the nonce). Still, [1844 Posts to correct (over all versions of the docs)](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3adoc.trolltech.com), some with loads of links, that's for a CM or dev to do with a script.

Comment: @rene Was my mistake, updated that. Thanks.

Comment: still a 4.6/4.8 mismatch but I see where you're going ...

Comment: Relevant [MSE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237110/is-there-any-support-for-mass-link-editing)

Comment: `http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.6/qgraphicsview.html` returns a 404, though.

Comment: @Cerbrus if that is the case an automatic conversion is out of the question, right?

Comment: Looks like it, @rene.

Comment: @Cerbrus: That's what I referred to. On further investigation, the wayback machine doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: Wayback machine does help a bit though, the few links I tested had several snapshots http://web.archive.org/web/20101006082654/http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qgraphicsview.html

Comment: Maybe use the [top Google hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+-inurl%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com+http%3A%2F%2Fdoc.trolltech.com%2F+-inurl%3Atagged+-inurl%3Asort%3Dactive+-inurLsort%3Dvotes+-inurl%3Arevisions+-inurl%3Asuggested-edits+-inurl%3Ahot) to prioritize?

Comment: The documentation for a few, older Qt versions is available here: http://doc.qt.io/archives/
E.g.: http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qgraphicsview.html

Comment: There's another [600+ posts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Adeveloper.qt.nokia.com) using links with nokia domains as well.